# Error when I try to Parse image of VUE to SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js

I have an application running SpringBoot with VUE. When I try to upload an image to the backend and save it in the database, I have this error:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `byte[]` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `byte[]` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 74] (through reference chain: com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.model.News["imgtitle"])]

My `News` Java class is:

```java
    package com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.model;
 

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "news")
    public class News {
     
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long id;
     
      @Column(name = "type")
      private String type;
    
      @Column(name = "title")
      private String title;
    
      @Column(name = "body")
      private String body;
     
      @Column(name = "created")
      private Date created;
     
      @Column(name = "updated")
      private Date updated;
    
      @Column(name = "user")
      private String user;
    
      @Column(name = "imgtitle")
      private byte[] imgtitle;
       
      public News(String type, String title, String body, Date created, Date updated, String user, byte[] imgtitle) {
        this.type = type;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.created = created;
        this.updated = updated;
        this.user = user;
        this.imgtitle = imgtitle;
      }
     
      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }
     
      public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
      }
     
      public String getType() {
        return this.type;
      }
    
      public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
      }
     
      public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
      }
    
      public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
      }
     
      public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
      }
     
      public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
      }
     
      public Date getCreated() {
        return this.created;
      }
     
      public Date getUpdated() {
        return this.updated;
      }
     
      public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
      }
    
      public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
      }
     
      public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
      }
    
      public byte[] getImgtitle() {
        return imgtitle;
    }
    public void setImgtitle(byte[] imgtitle) {
        this.imgtitle = imgtitle;
    }
     
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "News [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + ", body=" + body + ", body=" + body + ", created=" + created + ", updated=" + updated + ", user=" + user + ", imgtitle=" + imgtitle + "]";
      }
    }
```

My `NewsController`:

```java
    package com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.controller;
    
    import com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.model.News;
    import com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.repo.NewsRepository;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class NewsController {
      @Autowired
      NewsRepository repository;
    
      @GetMapping("/newsl")
      public List<News> getAllNewss() {
        System.out.println("Listando todas as notícias...");
    
        List<News> newsl = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(newsl::add);
    
        return newsl;
      } 
    
      @PostMapping("/news")
      public News postNews(@RequestBody News news) {
        News _news = repository.save(
          new News(
            news.getType(),
            news.getTitle(),
            news.getBody(),
            news.getCreated(),
            news.getUpdated(),
            news.getUser(),
            news.getImgtitle()
          )
        );
        return _news;
      } 
    
      @DeleteMapping("/news/{id}")
      public ResponseEntity<String> deleteNews(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Delete News with ID = " + id + "...");
    
        repository.deleteById(id);
    
        return new ResponseEntity<>("News has been deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
      }
    
      @GetMapping("newsl/body/{body}")
      public List<News> findByBody(@PathVariable String body) {
        List<News> newsl = repository.findByBody(body);
        return newsl;
      }
    
      @GetMapping("newsl/type/{type}")
      public List<News> findByType(@PathVariable String type) {
        List<News> newsl = repository.findByType(type);
        return newsl;
      }
    
      @GetMapping("newsl/user/{user}")
      public List<News> findByUser(@PathVariable String user) {
        List<News> newsl = repository.findByUser(user);
        return newsl;
      }
    
      @GetMapping("newsl/title/{title}")
      public List<News> findByTitle(@PathVariable String title) {
        List<News> newsl = repository.findByTitle(title);
        return newsl;
      }
    
      @PutMapping("/news/{id}")
      public ResponseEntity<News> updateNews(
        @PathVariable("id") long id,
        @RequestBody News news
      ) {
        System.out.println("Update News with ID = " + id + "...");
    
        Optional<News> newsData = repository.findById(id);
    
        if (newsData.isPresent()) {
          News _news = newsData.get();
          _news.setType(news.getType());
          _news.setTitle(news.getTitle());
          _news.setBody(news.getBody());
          _news.setCreated(news.getCreated());
          _news.setUpdated(news.getUpdated());
          _news.setUser(news.getUser());
          _news.setImgtitle(news.getImgtitle());
          return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.save(_news), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
      }
    }
```

My `NewsRepository`:

```java
    package com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.repo;
     
    import java.util.List;
     
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
     
    import com.gym.spring.restapi.mariadb.model.News;
     
    public interface NewsRepository extends CrudRepository<News, Long> {
      List<News> findByTitle(String title);
      List<News> findByBody(String body);
      List<News> findByUser(String user);
      List<News> findByType(String type);
      List<News> findByImgtitle(byte[] imgtitle);
    }
```

And finally my `Addnews.vue`:

```html
    <template>
      <div class="container-fluid uk-width-1-2@s">
        <div v-if="!submitted">      
             <input type="file" id="file" ref="myFiles" class="form-control" 
      @change="previewFiles" multiple/>
            <!--input
              type="file"
              class="form-control"
              id="imgtitle"
              required
              :v-model="news.imgtitle"
              name="imgtitle"
            />       
          <!--el-upload action="#" list-type="picture-card" :auto-upload="false">
            <i slot="default" class="el-icon-plus"></i>
            <div class="form-group" slot="file" slot-scope="{ file }">
              <img class="el-upload-list__item-thumbnail" :src="file.url" alt="" />
              <span class="el-upload-list__item-actions">
                <span
                  class="el-upload-list__item-preview"
                  @click="handlePictureCardPreview(file)"
                >
                  <i class="el-icon-zoom-in"></i>
                </span>
                <span
                  v-if="!disabled"
                  class="el-upload-list__item-delete"
                  @click="handleDownload(file)"
                >
                  <i class="el-icon-download"></i>
                </span>
                <span
                  v-if="!disabled"
                  class="el-upload-list__item-delete"
                  @click="handleRemove(file)"
                >
                  <i class="el-icon-delete"></i>
                </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </el-upload>
          <el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible">
            <img width="100%" :src="dialogImageUrl" alt="" />
          </el-dialog-->      
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type">Tipo</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="type"
              required
              v-model="news.type"
              name="type"
            />
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Título</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="title"
              required
              v-model="news.title"
              name="title"
            />
          </div>
    
          <div class="uk-container">
            <ckeditor
              :editor="editor"
              id="body"
              name="body"
              class="form-control"
              required
              v-model="news.body"
              :config="editorConfig"
            ></ckeditor>
          </div>
          <br />
          <button v-on:click="saveNews" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    
        <div v-else>
          <h4>Sua notícia foi enviada com sucesso!</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="newNews">
            Adicionar nova notícia
          </button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import http from "../http-common";
    import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
    import VueUploadMultipleImage from "vue-upload-multiple-image";
    
    export default {
      name: "add-news",
      data() {
        return {
          files: [],      
          dialogImageUrl: "",
          dialogVisible: false,
          disabled: false,
          editor: ClassicEditor,
          editorData: "<p>Digite aqui seu texto.</p>",
          editorConfig: {
            // The configuration of the editor.
          },
          news: {
            id: 0,
            type: "",
            title: "",
            body: "",
            created: "",
            updated: "",
            user: "",
            imgtitle: "",
          },
          submitted: false,
        };
      },
      components: {
        VueUploadMultipleImage,
      },
      methods: {
         previewFiles() {
        this.files = this.$refs.myFiles.files
      },
     /*    handleRemove(file) {
          console.log(file);
        },
        handlePictureCardPreview(file) {
          this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;
          this.dialogVisible = true; 
        },
        handleDownload(file) {     
          const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (event) => {
                console.log(event.target.result);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(file.url);          
              this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;   
        }, */
        saveNews() {        
          var data = {
            type: this.news.type,
            title: this.news.title,
            body: this.news.body,
            imgtitle: this.$refs.myFiles.files,
            editorData: this.editorData,
            created: new Date(),
            updated: new Date(),
            user: localStorage.name,
          };
          http
            .post("/news", data)
            .then((response) => {        
              this.news.id = response.data.id;
              // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
              console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
              console.log(e);
            });
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        newNews() {
          this.submitted = false;
          this.news = {};
        },
      },
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
    };
    </script>
    
    <style>
    .submitform {
      max-width: 300px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .ck-editor {
      width: 300px;
    }
    .ck-editor__editable {
      min-height: 500px;
    }
    #my-strictly-unique-vue-upload-multiple-image {
      font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Just a hint for the future: In 3 weeks, I'd have rewritten the whole code line-by-line checking for each line if the problem occurs now, so you (and we) would have a starting point for debugging.

Comment: Another hint: provide a simplified example code, domenstrating your problem. At least remove unused/commented code

Comment: dear friend, i have rewritten the code some times, if you cant help its okay, but don't comment what you don't know please.

Comment: Dear friend, no offense here, but if you've rewritten it for 3 weeks, where is the problem providing a minimal example? Do you expect us to read through 80% non-problem-specifc boilerplate code in our spare time?